# Comparing chars [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I got a little problem. I've been searching here, but I was unable to find anything, so, I want to compare 2 chars, for example:

```
char a;
char b[2][2] = {"a", "b"};
cin >> a; //For example I write an "a" letter here
//Then I want to compare them
if(strcmp(a, b[0]) == 0) {
    cout << "True";
}
```

But I get an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|
```

Yes, I know, it as as simple as that, but I just can't find the way how to solve this.

Comment: `strcmp` compares strings, not individual characters. You could write `a == b[0][0]`

Comment: `b[0]` is not a character though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some basics regarding C/C++ and `char` and `C string`s.

A string literal, like "a", or "b" are of type `const char []` (or `char const []`, they are the same) and it is NOT a `char`, but the standard also says,

> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”

In C/C++, if you want to compare two `char`s, you can just use `==` operator. If you want to compare two C strings (strings ends with null character), you can use `strcmp(char const * a, char const * b)`. Here a and b both have to be a `const char *`.  Also based on the standard, `const char []` can be converted to `const char *`.

You can also use string literals to initialize char arrays, like in your example, `b[2][2] = {"a", "b"}`.

Now b[0] is of type `char [2]` and can be converted to a `const char *`.  But in your sample code, `a` is a char, not a `char const *`

So for your code to work you can just `if (a == b[0][0])` which will compare two `char`s.

Comment: `"a"` is of type `char const[2]`. Arrays and pointers are different

Comment: I double checked, you are right. Let me fix the answer

Comment: @CSPei [String literals *are* arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). String literals, like all C-style arrays, decay into pointers to their first element which is why the misconception occurs so often.